# Java Scanner next() scanning in empty tokens

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a scanner to split up an IP address (String) into 4 ints. I used a delimiter and set the pattern to "."

next() Documentation:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

I initially tried using the IP String with no periods at the ends but I have now tried adding periods to each end of the string. Scanner next() still does not scan my numbers (or anything).

```
public void setIP(String ip){
    IPstring = "."+ip+".";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(IPstring);
    sc.useDelimiter(".");
    System.out.println(IPstring);
    System.out.println(sc.next());
    System.out.println(sc.next());
    System.out.println(sc.next());
    sc.close();
}
```

Output:

```
.216.198.240.0.
```

Note: there are 3 blank lines under .216.198.240.0.

I intend to replace the printlns with:

```
IP1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
IP2 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
IP3 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
IP4 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
```

IP1-4 are ints representing the 4 parts of the IP address.

Comment: The delimiter is a regex. You need to escape `.`.

Comment: Why are you using a `Scanner` for this? `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(InetAddress.getByName("216.198.240.0").getAddress()));`

Answer (score 3):

[The delimiter is a regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Scanner.html).

Use

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\.");
```